# Post-compilation sequence of C# custom attributes

Tags: c#-4.0

I have set of custom attributes, my logic reflects over applied attributes on specific properties. Part of the logic was trying to rely on the sequence in which the attributes are applied in he source code, however what I found after decompiling few timers that the C# compiler doesn’t put the attributes in IL in the same sequence as it appears in the source code. Any insight on this? I am not able to find any information about this in MSDN.

Comment: It is very bad practice to rely on attribute order - attributes are DECLARATIVE metadata, don't think imperatively! Also, the order can be changed at compilation, they can differ on inherited instances, etc. What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: Thanks for the comment. I understand, I am dealing with declarative metadata. It isnt mentioned anywhere in the documentation, so I was trying to understand whats the logic behind different sequence in IL everytime we compile. I was doing a little custom validation fraamework and some places, i had to evaluate conditions in certain order. I introduced a property - 'EvaluationOder' to my custom attribute, so it is no loger a problem, however I am curious to know what logic compiler applies, if any at all.